# how do i send request using skpayment for MultipleProduct Id's in IOS

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, payment-processing

In my project I have 5 products. So I need to buy 3 products to send payment request for those particular productID's, do I need to loop it like below.

```
for  (int i;i<[productsID's count];i++)
{
     skmutablepayment *payment =[skmutablepayment paymentwithproductidentifier:
                  [product objetatindex:i]];
}
```

I know we need to use quantity property but I need the payment only for specific products which I have selected. How do I pass those selected id's to skpayment?

Comment: I edited your question, you need to use a `IF` statement to check if the product is selected.

Comment: @JeremyThompson thanks for editing, i have selected and sorted the productID's in array, my question is how do i pass those selected id's to skpayment?